# How do I darken up my menu icon when you hover over it?

Tags: css, menu, hover, icons, dropdown

I have a button (dropbtn) and a Menu Icon (Menu). The button only works
When it's Z-Index is higher than the Menu Icons Z-Index. So I made the button transparent, so when you press the button it looks like you are pressing the Icon, but in fact you are actually pressing a button.

When I put the `<img>` inside the `<button>` the image was above the button, so it didn't work, because the image shouldn't be on top.

What did I try?

This doesn't work, because you are hovering over the Button.
You can't hover over the Menu, because it's below the Button.

```
.Logo:hover, .Logo:focus {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

What I want:

I want my Icon to darken up by lowering the opacity (the Icon is white and the background is dark) when hovering over the button. How do I make that happen?

It's not my main question, but when I want to be able to close the dropdown menu by pressing the Menu Icon, but now that doesn't work.

This is my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
     $("#myDropdown").fadeIn();
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            $("#myDropdown").fadeOut();
        }
    }
}

$(function()
{
    $("#btnButton1").click(myFunction);
});
```

```css
.Menu {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    top: 17px;
    left: 17px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index:5;
    color: white;
}

.dropbtn {
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    top: 17px;
    left: 17px;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 6;
    color: white;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    z-index: 3;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #000000;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    top: 60px;
    opacity: 0.3;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    padding: 13px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    opacity: 1
}

.dropdown a:hover {
    color: #d9d9d9;
}

.show {
    display:block;
}

.Logo {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 6;
    left: 50%;
    top: 14px;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.Logo:hover, .Logo:focus {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
 
.background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index:2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 220%;
    background-image:   url("http://www.dnsvnr.com/background1.jpg");
}

.fixedbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    opacity: 0.2;
    background-color: #000000;
}
.fixedbar {
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #3c3c3c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
<button id="btnButton1" class="dropbtn" >
</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="#about">About</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>

<img src="http://www.dnsvnr.com/Menu.png" width="24" height="24" class="Menu" />

<body>
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.dnsvnr.com/logo.png" class="Logo" width="32" height="32"/></a>
</body>
   
<nav class="background">
</nav>

<nav class="fixedbar">
</nav>
```

Comment: Typo: "When I put the inside the the image was..."

Comment: One thing about your fiddle, you have body tags outside the nav stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One fix, to close the menu

```
function myFunction() {
    if($("#myDropdown").is(":visible")){
        $("#myDropdown").fadeOut(); 
    } else {
        $("#myDropdown").fadeIn();
    //document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
```

Comment: How  do you know exactly how to do that, is it experience or did you do research? And is this "easy" for most developers? I think coding is really interesting and I am just curious. :)

Comment: Both. You remember seeing something (experience) and if you don't remember exactly how, you look it up. I remembered but had to check the syntax for `.is`. Please accept if it helped. (or wait for the other part to be answered.)

Comment: It helped a lot, I'll accept the answer and just ask the question again lol. thanks!

Comment: That's probably cool, but edit this question to just ask about closing the menu or your new one could be marked as a duplicate. (!) Tnx.